# What is h2 of the trapezoid base of this prism?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm trying to find h2 of a trapezoid base of a prism, but I can't figure it out. There aren't any angles or sides I know of I can use to determine the measurement

I'm looking for the smaller height of the trapezoid base, by $1.00$ and $.76$ measurements.
[image: I'm looking for the smaller height of the trapezoid base, by 1.00 and .76 measurements.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Colored floor plan]

Notice $\angle DEF = 45^\circ$, you have $\color{green}{FD} = \color{green}{DE}$ and
$$\begin{align} h_2 = \color{blue}{AF} &= AD - \color{green}{FD} = \color{orange}{BC} - \color{green}{DE} \\
& = \color{orange}{BC} - (DC - \color{#CCCC00}{EC}) = \color{orange}{BC} - (\color{red}{AB} - \color{#CCCC00}{EC})\\
&= 2.00 - (2.24 - 0.50) = 0.26\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question -- do you know how to calculate the height of the cut towards the bottom back is? Above the .54 measurement?

Comment: @ManaalSiddiqui Do you mean the back height of the region (with base 1.14 x 0.54) that get removed in the front. If that is the case, it is $0.26+0.54 = 0.80$. The slope of the slanted roof is $\tan 45^\circ = 1$. If you move forward for $x$ unit (ie. along the direction $AB$), the height will  increase for same $x$ unit.